# Woocommerce order dynamic output data is not working in WordPress Thickbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin to show live courier tracking result in woocommerce shop orders page.

Based on *[Add a custom ajax button to WooCommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650264/add-a-custom-ajax-button-to-woocommerce-admin-orders-list)* answer code to one of my previous questions, here is my new code attempt:

Adding Javascript code

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_footer_tracking_js' );
function admin_footer_tracking_js() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] ) :
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function trackParcel(orderId, parcelId){
         jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: {
                    'action':   'mark_message_as_read',
                    'dvs_order_id' : orderId,                    
                    'dvs_courier_tracking' : parcelId,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    jQuery('#track-thickbox').html(response);
                }
            });
    }

    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Adding Tracking Column

```
// add new column in admin order Tracking
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'dvs_add_tracking_admin_list_column' );
function dvs_add_tracking_admin_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['dvs_show_tracking'] = 'Tracking';
    return $columns;
}
```

Adding Tracking button in shop order column

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'dvs_add_tracking_admin_list_column_content' );
function dvs_add_tracking_admin_list_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'dvs_show_tracking' === $column ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $dvs_show_courier_list = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_dvs_courier_list', true );
        $dvs_show_courier_tracking = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_dvs_courier_tracking', true );
        add_thickbox();
        echo'<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=my-content-id" id="thickBoxLink" class="woocommerce-Button button thickbox" onclick="trackParcel(\'' . $order->get_id() . '\', \'' . $dvs_show_courier_tracking . '\')">Tracking</a>';

        ?>  
        <div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
        <p id='track-thickbox'>
        </p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Curl request to get live tracking

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mark_message_as_read', 'get_mark_message_as_read');
function get_mark_message_as_read() {
    $order = $_POST['dvs_order_id'];
    $tracking = $_POST['dvs_courier_tracking'];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://new.leopardscod.com/webservice/trackBookedPacket/format/json/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'api_key' => 'xxx',
        'api_password' => 'xxx',
        'track_numbers' => 'LE783655225'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $response; // Send data back to JS
    die();
}
```

As I am working with custom fields and curl response, I am adding the variable values below for the testing purpose

```
$dvs_show_courier_list = 'Leopards Courier'
```

```
$dvs_show_courier_tracking = 'LE783655225'
```

```
$response = {"status":1,"error":0,"packet_list":[{"booked_packet_id":"31134748","booking_date":"06\/01\/2021","track_number":"LE783596151","track_number_short":"783596151","booked_packet_weight":"250","arival_dispatch_weight":"33","booked_packet_vol_weight_w":"0","booked_packet_vol_weight_h":null,"booked_packet_vol_weight_l":null,"booked_packet_no_piece":"1","booked_packet_collect_amount":"1000.00","booked_packet_order_id":"10564","origin_country_name":"PAKISTAN\r","origin_city_name":"LAHORE","destination_city_name":"KARACHI","invoice_number":"IBLE5046889","invoice_date":"2021-01-14","shipment_name_eng":"Printed Mobile Covers","shipment_email":"hello@covers.pk","shipment_phone":"03038518000","shipment_address":"HOUSE # 310 KAMRAN BLOCK ALLAMA IQBAL TOWN LAHORE","consignment_name_eng":"Saad","consignment_email":"saadaftab1990@gmail.com","consignment_phone":"03212568327","consignment_phone_two":"0","consignment_phone_three":"0","consignment_address":"Flat# A-38, 1st floor, Saghir Centre, FB area, Block 16","special_instructions":"Mobile Covers - Handle with care - Donot Add Fake Status - WhatsApp 03038518000","booked_packet_status":"Delivered","status_remarks":"Array\/Array","Tracking Detail":[{"Status":"Shipment picked in  LAHORE MAIN CITY","Activity_Date":"2021-01-07","Activity_Time":"00:32:08","Activity_datetime":"2021-01-07 00:32:08"},{"Status":"Dispatched to KHI MAIN OFFICE","Activity_Date":"2021-01-07","Activity_Time":"00:59:35","Activity_datetime":"2021-01-07 00:59:35"},{"Status":"Arrived at Station in KARACHI LOCAL","Reciever_Name":null,"Activity_Date":"2021-01-09","Activity_Time":"03:52:31","Reason":null,"Activity_datetime":"2021-01-09 03:52:31"},{"Status":"Arrived at Station in SOHRAB GOTH","Reciever_Name":null,"Activity_Date":"2021-01-09","Activity_Time":"08:12:57","Reason":null,"Activity_datetime":"2021-01-09 08:12:57"},{"Status":"Assigned to courier in SOHRAB GOTH","Reciever_Name":null,"Activity_Date":"2021-01-09","Activity_Time":"11:16:09","Reason":null,"Activity_datetime":"2021-01-09 11:16:09"},{"Status":"Delivered","Reciever_Name":"SAAD","Activity_Date":"2021-01-09","Activity_Time":"22:22:00","Reason":"SELF","Activity_datetime":"2021-01-09 22:22:00"}]}]}
```

The code works and displays data in the console but not in the output.

[image]

Can someone please guide what I did wrong?

Comment: You need to parse the JSON data from '$response' variable in the function `get_mark_message_as_read()`into readable structured html code that you will echo (to get it back in Javascript success response)… Now nobody can help you here as your code is not testable… You need to build for StackOverFlow a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) with a JSON off static data and the missing function that adds a custom column in admin orders list.

Comment: Sir, I have edited the question with missing details. Regards

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sir, I observed one more thing, in the shop order page if in screen option no of item per page = 1 then it displays the output perfectly. But If I set it to any number except 1 then it did not give output, it remains show data in the console. Video: https://www.loom.com/share/fde6b39e776c491a85233dedeceefdc3

Comment: You should add in your question an example of JSON output for `$response` and also for `$dvs_show_courier_list`, `$dvs_show_courier_tracking` custom fields… This way it will make your code testable... Without it, nobody can really test your issue.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry my bad, I have edited the question and provided the values that I am using in curl request and also $reponse output

Answer (score 0):

After multiple tries, I figure out the solution. When we use Thickbox we need to take care of HTML tags e.g id, class.

I was using ID inside ID so it was not correct. So I change it to

```
<div id="my-content-id" style="display:none;">
 <p class='track-thickbox'>
 </p>
</div>
```

and problem solved.